# how to connect RSS feed in AMP application

Tags: amp-html

i want to integrate RSS feed into my AMP application but i didn't find any documentation about this, is this possible to parse xml to json in AMP?

anyone of you deal this in AMP? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AMP-Bind](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/) with [AMP-List](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list/) on a [Mustache-Template](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-mustache/)
But you must use a JSON request. you can generate a JSON from your XML with PHP.

Comment: Ok, it is impossible to parse xml to json inside AMP right? we need to parse in server side then only AMP access JSON